# About Coredata "IN" & "NOT IN"

Tags: core-data

SQL Statement
  SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ACTION IN ('A','B');

The following code is throwing an exception

```
- (NSArray*) fetchManagedObjects:(NSString*)className withFlag:(NSString*)flag{
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    fetchRequest.entity = entity;
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@" ( 1== 1 ) "];
    if ([className isEqualToString:@"Entity3"]) {
        [str appendFormat:@" AND ( kfollowAction IN ('%@')  ) ", flag];
    }
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:str];
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *entities = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return entities;
}
```

> 2013-06-20 16:45:51.318 CNPL[1447:1a903] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16965b30'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x3647012 0x2ea2e7e 0x36d24bd 0x3636bbc 0x363694e 0x192966c 0x1928e06 0x191b829 0x191ad08 0x1915915 0x19155f2
>   0x19153c0 0x1915195 0x1914977 0x1914464 0x19135dd 0x1911539 0xdce02
>   0xe261a 0x1ec81c7 0x1ec8232 0x1ec84da 0x1edf8e5 0x1edf9cb 0x1edfc76
>   0x1edfd71 0x1ee089b 0x1ee0e93 0x1ee0a88 0xe1dd3 0x2eb6705 0x1dea2c0
>   0x1dea258 0x1eab021 0x1eab57f 0x1eaa6e8 0x1e19cef 0x1e19f02 0x1df7d4a
>   0x1de9698 0x3909df9 0x3909ad0 0x35bcbf5 0x35bc962 0x35edbb6 0x35ecf44
>   0x35ece1b 0x39087e3 0x3908668 0x1de6ffc 0x1ab1a 0x2f35)

How to use Coredata?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: ***Never*** use `stringWithFormat` to build a predicate. The format specifiers
and quoting works differently in `stringWithFormat` and `predicateWithFormat`, so using string
formatting functions for predicates is *very* error-prone.
If you have to combine predicates at runtime,
use the methods from `NSCompoundPredicate`.

Now to select objects where the "kfollowAction" attribute has one of the values in a given list,
you have to use the "IN" operator with an *array*, for example:

```
NSArray *flags = @[@"A", @"B"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"kfollowAction IN %@", flags];
```

There is also no need for a dummy predicate "( 1== 1 )". If you want to fetch all objects,
then just don't set a predicate for the fetch request.

Comment: @user2474198: Please show your updated code, otherwise I cannot help.